# How to sort a rectangular array upon a specific values of the cells in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a rectangular array consists of zeros and ones. I need to obtain a path which consists of the indexes of the ones. I need to obtain the best one i.e. the best path which is the longest in terms of the number of ones that can be connected to each other from the starting point. The path is a group of ones that can be connected to each other: vertically, horizontally or diagonally and you can move using all these directions.

Comment: Given there are so many other alternatives  - how did you as a human pick that one over the others?

Comment: What makes that path the "best" path? You seem to be saying the "best" path has the longest chain of `1` values, but it looks to me as though you could add more `1` cells to the path you've drawn without repeating cells, so according to my understanding of your "best" path, the one you drew isn't it. Can you apply maze-solving algorithms to the problem? Have you tried a backtracking algorithm? How large an array is the solution supposed to be able to handle? Your question is incredibly vague.

Comment: @Isra' but you havnt answer the question. if you cant explain to us in human terms, then thats whats wrong.. You cant explain in english how do you expect to translate to another language?

Comment: @Isra': If you cannot show us an example that explains all rules of pathfinding (which this example does not), then you need to mention the rules of pathfinding. Can a line cross itself? Does it need to start from a given position, or is the aim to find the longest path no matter where it begins? You need to provide the **full** list of requirements and rules. Also, your code sample needs some condensing, there are a ton of unnecessary blank lines.

Comment: @Isra': In regards to me editing your question: Give a man a fish, or teach a man to fish? I pick the latter.

Comment: Plug in A* and get the longest path.

Comment: @the_lotus A* will probably behave worse (and be far more complicated) than pure recursion, since it is optimized for shortest path.  In-fact, unmodified, A* will stop once it finds a solution.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: If unmodified A* stops once it finds a solution; then it can't be optimized to find the shortest path, can it? (as it does not calculate and compare alternatives) These things seems to contradict eachother. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Flater you are correct. That should say that it stops after finding the shortest path. It doesn't need to check every possible path though, eventually it can know that all remaining possible paths are longer, and terminate without having to walk them.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: Fair enough. So A* is designed in a way that shorter paths tend to be found faster than longer paths; rather than paths being calculated randomly (with an unpredictable length) and later compared, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Flater exactly. That's the purpose of the heuristic function in A*. It allows choices to be pre sorted based on the ones that are most likely to succeed.

Comment: @BradleyUffner my mistake... seems like this is a NP-hard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple recursive algorithm to traverse the entire array. For each call to the function, you get a list of cells you already visited ("the path") and the current cell you've just entered.

You add the current cell to the list, and look around the cell you're in for any "1" cells which are not in your path list.

If you have no "1" cells around you which are not in the path list, return the path list.

If you do have "1" cells around you which you have not yet visited, use your function recursively on each cell with the path you have so far, compare their return result paths by length, and return the longest path.

Code example added:

```
        using System;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Collections;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Threading;
        using AUV_Topology;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Media;
        using System.Linq;

        namespace AUVtopology
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {        
              static int[,] array;
              static List<int[]> path;
        //This method is used to make sure the coordinate array 
        //is contained in the list. List.contains(new int[] {val1,val2}) was not enough.
        static Boolean containsArray(List<int[]> list, int[] array)
        {
            if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            foreach (var listArray in list)
            {
                if (listArray != null && listArray.Length == array.Length)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (array[i] != listArray[i])
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }    

        //This is the recursive method of the algorithm. It finds the 
        //maximum path of 1 cells in a matrix of 0/1 cells
        static List<int[]> getMaxPath(int[,] array, List<int[]> maxPath, int rowIndex, int colIndex)
        {  
                 //End case in which we started (or ended up) in a 0 cell
                 if (array[rowIndex,colIndex] != 1) {
                     return maxPath;
                 }

                 //if we back-tracked and this cell was visited
                 if (containsArray(maxPath, new int[]{rowIndex,colIndex})) {
                     return maxPath;
                 }

                 //Add the current cell to the path.
                 maxPath.Add(new int[]{rowIndex,colIndex});

                 //Get the array limits.
                 int rowLength = array.GetLength(0);
                 int colLength = array.GetLength(1);

                 //If the path contains all the cells in the matrix, stop
                 if (maxPath.Count >= rowLength * colLength) {
                     return maxPath;
                 }

                 //remove one from lengths to make it the maximum index
                 colLength = colLength - 1;
                 rowLength = rowLength - 1;

                 //We'll use this variables to see which of the 
                 //potential 7 paths is the longest.
                 List<int[]> futurePath;

                 //Go over all 8 possible adjoining cells:
                 //If we can go one down, one right
                 if (colIndex < colLength && rowIndex < rowLength) {

                        //We use maxPath first, since this is the first 
                        //direction and by default is the longest
                        maxPath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex+1, colIndex+1);
                 } 

                 //If we can go one down
                 if (colIndex < colLength) {

                       //We use futurePath now, since this is a second
                       //direction and a potential contender
                       futurePath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex, colIndex+1);

                      //We only need the maximum path.
                      if (futurePath.Count > maxPath.Count) {
                          maxPath = futurePath;
                      }
                 } 

                 //If we can go one down and one left
                 if (rowIndex>0 && colIndex < colLength) {

                         futurePath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex-1, colIndex+1);
                         if (futurePath.Count > maxPath.Count) {
                             maxPath = futurePath;
                         }
                 }

                 //If we can go one left
                 if (rowIndex>0) {

                         futurePath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex-1, colIndex);
                         if (futurePath.Count > maxPath.Count) {
                             maxPath = futurePath;
                         }
                 }
                 //If we can go one left and one up
                 if (rowIndex>0 && colIndex>0) {

                     futurePath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex-1, colIndex-1);
                     if (futurePath.Count > maxPath.Count) {
                          maxPath = futurePath;
                     }
                 }                 
                 //If we can go one up
                 if (colIndex>0) {

                         futurePath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex, colIndex-1);
                         if (futurePath.Count > maxPath.Count) {
                             maxPath = futurePath;
                         }
                 }
                 //If we can go one up and one right
                 if (colIndex>0 && rowIndex < rowLength) {

                    futurePath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex+1, colIndex-1);
                    if (futurePath.Count > maxPath.Count) {
                         maxPath = futurePath;
                    }
                 }
                 //If we can go one right
                 if (rowIndex < rowLength) {

                     futurePath = getMaxPath (array, maxPath, rowIndex+1, colIndex);
                     if (futurePath.Count > maxPath.Count) {
                         maxPath = futurePath;
                     }
                 }

                //We return the max path. Note: If none of the directions around 
                //us was applicable, we simply return the path we started 
                //with with our cell included.
                return maxPath;
          }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148128/discussion-on-answer-by-assafs-how-to-analyze-a-rectangular-array-and-obtain-the).

Comment: I can do no more here, sorry. I suggest you recruit a c# programmer to help you run and debug the code. After three days of flying blind and trying out various approaches, I must admit there's nothing that can replace running the code and debugging it in real time. Good luck to you.

Comment: You check it in the entrance to the function:

static List<int[]> getMaxPath(int[,] array, List<int[]> maxPath, int rowIndex, int colIndex)
        {  
                 //End case in which we started (or ended up) in a 0 cell
                 if (array[rowIndex,colIndex] != 1) {
                     return maxPath;
                 }